# Issue while setting WindowSoftInputMode to AdjustPan

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio, xamarin.mac

I’m working on Xamarin forms project. I’ve many Entry fields in my application, one of them is in popup and the popup opens in the centre of the device screen. Also few entry fields are in scroll view. The issue is only with the Android Application. For iOS it’s working perfectly.
When I click on Entry field in side the popup, the soft key board is opened and the UI of my popup gets disturbed. So, I decided to set 
**WindowSoftInputMode = SoftInput.AdjustPan** to my main Activity. This solves my UI issue of the popups but now when I click on other entry fields,my **![scroll view stops scrolling]** (few entry fields are in side scrollview).I tried by using AdjustResize and rest of other soft inputs, but of no use. 
Any ideas on how to get rid of this ?

[image: Initial popup UI]

[image: softkey_board_open]

[image: softkey_board_closed]

Answer (score 4):

On Android Xamarin.Forms Application is working on a single Android Activity, so `WindowSoftInputMode` is set globally. You could do a dependency injection service. On iOS it would do nothing and on Android it would set `WindowSoftInputMode` to your desired value. Then use it to set `WindowSoftInputMode` before and after showing your Popup.

In Xamarin.Forms `Forms.Context` is the Activity.

```
var window = ((Activity)Forms.Context).Window;
window.SetSoftInputMode(SoftInput.AdjustPan);
```

Answer (score -1):

In case of

> Xamarin Android

you can access window directly from mainActivity Like so:

```
Window.SetSoftInputMode(Android.Views.SoftInput.AdjustPan);
```

or in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity android:name=".myActivity"
 android:label="@string/app_name"
 android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"/>
```

Comment: @Amrut has already tried this approach, but it won't work because it sets it globally, and thus changes the behavior on pages that don't need it.

Comment: Would you mind to read my responce again: In case of Xamarin Android, and @Amrut is talking about XF, thanks for the dislike I got a new badge

Comment: Then why are you giving a Xamarin Android answer to a Xamarin Forms question?

Comment: maybe it will help someone